# from GUI import *

Tags: python, module

I got this code in Python 2.7:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
import logging
import math
import operator
import pickle
import re
import sys
import threading
import time
import unicodedata
from random import shuffle

import currencylayer
import quandl
import requests
from GUI import *
from arduinoSerial import *
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from ledDisplay import *
from timeout import timeout
```

When I run it an error occurs:

```
from GUI import *
ImportError: No module named GUI
```

I try to install GUI, but I couldnt:

```
Try to run this command from the system terminal. Make sure that you use the correct version of 'pip' installed for your Python interpreter located at '/home/in/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/bin/python
```

Did I made somehting bad? Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a module called "GUI" that you're trying to import?

Tkinter is the standard Python GUI framework. Maybe you're thinking of that, in which case you would need to use `from tkinter import *`.

Comment: Yes, is a code they give me, maybe its not complete?

Comment: Is there a file called GUI.py? If so, is it in the same directory as your script?

Comment: No, no GUI.py is in the archive. Maybe is that?

Comment: That's probably your issue. The easiest thing to do it to move GUI.py (and any .py files it depends on) to the same folder as your script.

If you want to keep GUI.py in another directory, there are ways to import it, but it gets a little more complicated.

If you want to know more, maybe take a look at the [documentation on the import system](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html).